# Text Opacity problem (1px glow)

Tags: jquery, css, filter, opacity

I've got a problem!
I need to have opacity on a text.

I try with jquery:

`$(document).ready(function() {

 $(".item h2").css({ opacity: 0.5 });
 });`

and with css:

`-moz-opacity:.50; -ms-filter:"alpha(opacity=50)"; filter:alpha(opacity=50); opacity:.50;`

but all times i see a little glow (1px) around my text in Firefox and IE.
Chrome is ok!!
Anyone have a solution?!?!
Thx a lot

Comment: I think I know what you're talking about, but you should probably add a screenshot to make the issue clear.

Comment: I'm sorry...my "reputation" is less than 10...i can't upload img..DAMN!!!!!!

Comment: Upload it to http://imgur.com/ yourself and write the link :/

Comment: THX Thirtydot!!! here the link: http://imgur.com/VqtoI

Answer (score 0):

Looks ok to me. Tested in FF4 and IE9/8/7
http://jsfiddle.net/aZC7v/

Sometimes a solution for this kind of problem is adding a background-color to the element. (either .item or the h2)